# df won't update using .at and print doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I'm trying to update a field in my DF (last row of the code).
To save some running time i'm subsetting my df.
for convenience reasons i'm also trying to print the value assigned to the df 
but :

1. I don't see the variables (a, temp_list) in the Variable Explorer
2. the df doesn't update (the value is still Nan after checking the df in variable explorer)
3. i'm updating the "if" filter at `Matched_amounts = df759['amount'][NO_Hatama_Filter]` - maybe you can suggest a more
   elegant way to update the Filter through iteration.
4. print command doesn't work

   ```
   Matched_amounts = df759['amount'][NO_Hatama_Filter]

   for index,row in match759[Summed_1].iterrows():
       mashlim = -1.00*(match759['Rell_Amount'][index])
       if mashlim in Matched_amounts:
             temp_list = Matched_amounts.index[Matched_amounts.loc[:'amount'] == mashlim]
             Matched_amounts = df759['amount'][NO_Hatama_Filter]
             index_hatama = temp_list[0]
             a = match759['Match'][index]
             print (a)
             df759.at[index_hatama, 'Hatama_EY'] = a
   ```

please help! 
thanks

Comment: Is it possible that `mashlim in Matched_amounts` on line 5 evaluates to false?

Comment: Hi - no - it's an actual number. this list has no nulls

Comment: But it might not be in `Matched_amounts`. I don't know much about your code, but from what I can see, I don't see why `mashlim in Matched_amounts` *would* evaluate to `True`.

It seems like all of the problems you've mentioned cover all of the logic that happens in that `if` block, so I'm thinking the condition evaluates to `False` and so the block below does not execute.

Comment: i'm trying to print the mashlim before executing the if
it doesn't print. and the variable doesn't appear in the variable explorer
i don't mind adding a prntscrn

Comment: Hmm, perhaps `match759[Summed_1]` is empty so there are no values to iterate over?

Comment: Yes Eventually one of the filters wasn't up to date.
thanks!